# Obtener array con números aleatorios en C usando punteros

Tags: c

Llevo rato tratando de obtener un array con X cantidad de enteros aleatorios usando punteros en C. Se me dificulta mucho el uso de los punteros y no logro dar con el resultado deseado. He trasteado bastante, pero no pasa de la línea que dice `*(vertices+i) = numAleatorio;`.

```
int main(){
 int v, o, d, i, numAleatorio, fparar, *vertices;
 vertices = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*v);
 printf("hola1\n");
 for(i = 0; i< v; i++){
    printf("hola2\n");
    do{
        printf("hola3\n");
        numAleatorio = rand() % (v + 1);
        printf("%d",numAleatorio);
        fparar = buscarNumero(numAleatorio, *vertices, v);
    }while(fparar);
    *(vertices+i) = numAleatorio;
    fprintf("%d", *(vertices+i));
    printf("hola7\n");
 }
}
int buscarNumero(int numero, int *arreglo[], int v){
 int i, parar = 0, *ptr;
 printf("hola4\n");

 for(i = 0;(i < v && parar == 0); i++){
    printf("hola5\n");

    if(*(arreglo+i) == numero){
        parar = 1;
    }
 }
 printf("hola6\n");
 printf("%d",parar);
 return parar;
}
```

Comment: ¿Te diste cuenta de que `v` está sin inicializar? Por lo tanto estás reservando una cantidad aleatoria de memoria. Si explicaras que es lo que quieres hacer podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: El fin es obtener cierta cantidad de enteros(la cantidad se agrega vía teclado) aleatorios no repetidos, para después iterárselos a unas funciones que harán un DFS(aunque con eso no tengo problema). Lo único que necesito es que me regrese el arreglo con los enteros ale

Answer (score 1):

Algunos problemas:

- No sé que quisiste hacer en la función `buscarNumero` pero no necesitas pasar un puntero a un arreglo ya que [los arreglos decaen en punteros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion). Podrías simplemente haber escrito `int arreglo[]` o `int* arreglo`.
- Puedes reescribir `*(arreglo + 1)` de una forma más familiar: `arreglo[i]`.
- Al llamar la función, se desreferencia `vertices`. O sea, la función recibe un entero. [El compilador](https://tio.run/##bVHBboMwDL3zFVanVgnNpvZMW2k/sB@YdkhDaCMFggxk0ia@nTmQbFSaD054efazH@r5ptQ0PZlG2aHUcOr60riX@yV7gKy5BiwzTQ/XoVMS34Zao2MECKCUz5kXC6WWpmH8OwsYeDjD8SDACSiJJaAZ6lerZe/QEFa1EiUKyL3G3ijdFRmkK1UGBch5La11inXmS7sqYDz3pAaVQ2aIdijAnMBT3u@DMEXpljPEWpLYKJuScdgC87CHY2gUY5mGKA9bPk78O6kAH0vHz7uxmi3VEUusd/NB/dYtlveqRdqjYpttuRFrdqgfs/F/t0Mjus52Qy4R9c3GL58cJ4/TGuR73vZI/2VlFR3kFex2iUYgT9bNs5mKxdbz9Oeoyv8cTQLHaEAYGVD3AzbLW5GN0/QD) te da una advertencia al respecto. Entonces cuando la función quiere leer el arreglo, accede a una dirección de memoria inválida, por eso el programa se cuelga u obtienes *Segmentation fault* en Linux.
- Escribiste `fprintf` en lugar de `printf`.

Con estas correcciones el programa no es errores pero no funciona bien. Así que decidí reescribir un poco el código arreglándolo y haciéndolo más simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generarNumero(int[], int);

int buscarNumero(int, int[], int);

int main(){
    int n = 10;
    int* vertices = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vertices[i] = generarNumero(vertices, n);
        printf("%d\n", vertices[i]);
    }
}

int buscarNumero(int numero, int arreglo[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (arreglo[i] == numero){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int generarNumero(int vertices[], int n){
    int numAleatorio;
    do {
        numAleatorio = rand() % (n + 1);
    } while(buscarNumero(numAleatorio,  vertices, n));
    return numAleatorio;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVHBboMwDL3zFVanSklhE5zbTtoP7Ae6HmgI1FJwphA2aRXfzhIIA6pNmg@Y2M/287N4rITo@wckodpCwqGxBeqn63O0Cim8rGMWa@kjEZKFSpI0uXlta2k0c5HTOQHn@H7MX9pGLNND8g5T50iM3yJw5t8ER8jS/fTewYc0FoVsXLzOldKCNfgldekbctgB8RHcmJwK5vmxlIdYqQ14HKCrTvfOHYCci@Mw0ds04IRnh1rvNOWSnzHe3o3rWbLNtnijTbJsEEBd1P2uANDwOygAuTGyUjoI4ibc/k8aS2BTved9DJ0XEG9G2tYQZDP3Lpq/IevU7v446LzbHcmwy4uSudUG9Tig0DDPX6bdJsN5OGyBEcSQTUrB5xWVZCuhlpXJfCB/hFAWmK8ZdH3/DQ).